# Mydomain error in Magento module

Tags: php, magento, b2b

I am installing a B2B extension on a local machine for Magento without trouble. But while doing the same for the client server I am getting following error:

```
404 Not Found

The server can not find the requested page:

mydomain.com/errors/report.php?id=264218583315&skin=default (port 80)
Please forward this error screen to mydomain.com's WebMaster.
```

Where do I need to do the changes? I replaced the following line 33 in Observer.php file.

```
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("customer/account/login"));
```

with

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect("http://mydomain.com/magento/index.php/customer/account/login"));
```

Also when I insert the url

```
http://mydomain.com/magento/index.php/customer/account/login
```

in the browser directly it works fine. But here its redirecting to 404 error page.

Do I need to make some changes to any file in Magento or some other configurations?

Comment: After some testing I come to the conclusion that it is a problem of access rights. But I am not able to find out which access rights should be given, so that it will work properly.

Comment: you aren't using any hosts file hacks for DNS are you? :)

Comment: I am not using any hosts file.

Comment: I have solved the problem adding javascript in default:
`<script type="text/javascript">
                                       window.location.href= "customer/account/login/key/78295b09aedf841b438c8742d1eeb129/";
                               </script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess This is an error with the configuration or with the installation of B2B Extension. Your configuration is stored in core_config table, also try to reinstall the B2B extension. As mentioned by LittleBigDev It can also be an issue with access rights. And do check the version of magento is same on local as well as server.

Answer (score 1):

Files' access rights should be 644.
For folders it should be 755.
For Mage folder's files and PEAR lib files it should be 550

And you should also check the files owner settings.

For more info, look at http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions/