# Redirect to google or any other website using magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to redirect to google.com using Magento.

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect('http://google.co.in'));
```

But when I use this code I am not able to open my home page too. It shows blank page.

What other code I can use instead of this so I can redirect to google.com?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect('http://google.com');
```

Also, in your example you end with a double ), that might be the problem in your code.

Comment: Actually I am using B2B extension and I am doing changes in Observer.php file also you can see my question here as I am having a problem in redirecting url "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494228/mydomain-error-in-magento-module"

Comment: In that question you made the same mistake, are you sure it's not just a double ending parentheses that is causing trouble?

Comment: ok thanks. It was problem of double ending parentheses. But it is working on local machine only. But not on client server as mentions in problem in above link

Comment: To what address is your browser redirecting instead of google?

Comment: its giving me error : 404 not found 
mydomain.com/errors/report.php?id=672761817356&skin=default (port 80)

Comment: Did you clear your cache? If that didn't help, what does your log say? var/log/exception.log and var/log/system.log of your server that gives 404

Comment: There is no file var/log/exception.log. In var/log/system.log

2012-09-19T10:00:00+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null gi$
2012-09-19T10:00:00+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, n$

Comment: Can you paste the last few lines on a pastebin or something? And did you clear magento's cache?

Comment: 2012-09-19T10:00:00+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null gi$ 2012-09-19T10:00:00+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, n$

I had cleared magento's cache too.

Answer (score 0):

try

`Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendHeaders()->sendResponse();

exit();`

Comment: Its working fine on local, but my problem is its not working on client's server. See my question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494228/mydomain-error-in-magento-module